# How to insert non-duplicate value into PostgreSQL from 2 different server

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to merge two table from different server in postgres. But it keep saying I have syntax error

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO Property__C VALUES IF NOT EXISTS(1,'a0236000002N...
```

Please help or any other way to merge 2 table from different server?

```
import psycopg2

heroku_conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = '@@@@@' user = '@@@@@' password = '@@@@' host = '@@@' port = '@@@'")
heroku_cur = heroku_conn.cursor()

local_conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = '***' user = '***' password = '***' host = 'localhost' port = '***'")
local_cur = local_conn.cursor()

def create_table_local_postgres():
    local_cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Property__C (ID NUMERIC, SFID TEXT, NAME TEXT, THUMBNAIL__C TEXT, BEDS__C NUMERIC, ADDRESS__C TEXT, BATHS__C NUMERIC,  BROKER__C TEXT, DESCRIPTION__C TEXT, STATE TEXT, CITY__C TEXT, ZIP__C NUMERIC, TITLE__C TEXT, PICTURE__C TEXT, PRICE__C REAL, LOCATION__LATITUDE__S NUMERIC, LOCATION__LONGITUDE__S NUMERIC)")
    local_conn.commit()
    local_conn.close()

def insert_local_postgres():
    heroku_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM property__c")
    row = heroku_cur.fetchall()
    for item in row:
        ID = item[0]
        SFID = item[1]
        NAME = item[2]
        THUMBNAIL__C = item[3]
        BEDS__C = item[4]
        ADDRESS__C = item[5]
        BATHS__C = item[6]
        BROKER__C = item[7]
        DESCRIPTION__C = item[8]
        STATE = item[9]
        CITY__C = item[10]
        ZIP__C = item[11]
        TITLE__C = item[12]
        PICTURE__C = item[13]
        PRICE__C = item[14]
        LOCATION__LATITUDE__S = item[15]
        LOCATION__LONGITUDE__S = item[16]
        local_cur.execute("INSERT INTO Property__C VALUES IF NOT EXISTS(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (ID, SFID, NAME, THUMBNAIL__C, BEDS__C, ADDRESS__C, BATHS__C,  BROKER__C, DESCRIPTION__C, STATE, CITY__C, ZIP__C, TITLE__C, PICTURE__C, PRICE__C, LOCATION__LATITUDE__S, LOCATION__LONGITUDE__S))
        print(item)
        print('\n')
    local_conn.commit()
    local_conn.close()
```

Comment: What is your Postgres version?

Comment: `INSERT INTO Property__C VALUES IF NOT EXISTS` is not correct SQL syntax. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: You should to use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` approach

Comment: im using postgreSQL 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by add a for loop instead of using SQL.
If there are any better solution, please let me know.
I'm using postgreSQL 12.

```
def insert_heroku_postgres():
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = '***' user = '***' password = '***' host = '***' port = '***'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print("connected with heroku postgres")
        
    local_conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = '***' user = '***' password = '***' host = '***' port = '***'")
    local_cur = local_conn.cursor()
    print("connected with local postgres")
    
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM property__c")
    row = cur.fetchall()  
    
    local_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM property__c")
    local_row = local_cur.fetchall()
    
    for item, item2, in itertools.zip_longest(row, local_row):
        ID = item2[0]
        SFID = item2[1]
        NAME = item2[2]
        THUMBNAIL__C = item2[3]
        BEDS__C = item2[4]
        ADDRESS__C = item2[5]
        BATHS__C = item2[6]
        BROKER__C = item2[7]
        DESCRIPTION__C = item2[8]
        STATE = item2[9]
        CITY__C = item2[10]
        ZIP__C = item2[11]
        TITLE__C = item2[12]
        PICTURE__C = item2[13]
        PRICE__C = item2[14]
        LOCATION__LATITUDE__S = item2[15]
        LOCATION__LONGITUDE__S = item2[16]
        
        if item is None:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO Property__C VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (ID, SFID, NAME, THUMBNAIL__C, BEDS__C, ADDRESS__C, BATHS__C,  BROKER__C, DESCRIPTION__C, STATE, CITY__C, ZIP__C, TITLE__C, PICTURE__C, PRICE__C, LOCATION__LATITUDE__S, LOCATION__LONGITUDE__S))
            
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```